# Angular routinfg. Using different component instances for same path

Tags: angular

Consider the following routes

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'default'
    },
    {
        path: 'default',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        component: DefaultComponent
    },
    {
        path: ':customViewId',
        component: CustomViewComponent
    }
];
```

There can be nearly 20 different values of `customViewId`, on each of them `CustomViewComponent` should get json describing a form and render that form. When a user switches tabs I dont want to destroy component, so that when user returns to that tab there's form with user input. That can be done with providing `RouteReuseStrategy`.

Still there's another problem I can't solve. If I use config above, same `CustomViewComponent` will be used for any `customViewId`. How can I make router create a new instance of `CustomViewComponent` for every value of `customViewId`? I don't want to list all 20 possible values in array